# .net core 3.1 disable automatic HTTPS redirection

Tags: redirect, .net-core, https

in my .net app, I have 2 listeners, one on HTTP port(`8090`) and another on HTTPS port(`8091`, self signed certificate is used). Server starts and listens on both ports. `app.UseHsts()` and `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` are commented(disabled).
After invoking `GET` method from "chrome" browser, I get `307 - Temporary Redirect` status code with location to port `8091` (HTTPS).
What I would like to have(expect) is, that if I call HTTP, then should get HTTP response from invoked controller/method, not redirection to HTTPS.

Is there any settings/configuration to prevent automatic redirects?

Answer (score 0):

This app works as a host for itself and also load plugin modules. One plugin actually called "UseHttpsRedirection()". Logical consequence was then redirecting with 307 status code. Disabling this plugin solved problem.